# C#: Cannot locate System libraries

Tags: c#

I have just looked in my regedit and found I am running .NET Version 4.5.1 and therefore the libraries I am after should be available to me.

I try to include the namespaces:

```
using System.IO.MemoryStream;
using System.Media.SoundPlayer;
```

However VS complains that the namespaces do not exist.

The reference pages for [MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SoundPlayer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx) dictate that these should be available in my version of .NET.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Are they visible under References in your project?

Comment: Yes they are...the only thing I can think is that I recently installed an add-on to VS and since then I've been having troubles such as syntax highlighting crashing at random intervals.

Comment: `System.IO` is a namespace, `System.IO.MemoryStream` is a class. You want `using System.IO;` and `using System.Media;`. Then you can use the `MemoryStream` and `SoundPlayer` classes.

Comment: I'm running a Console app

Comment: Ahh that makes sense.  Why is it with some namespaces you can provide multiple extensions, such as System.IO.Pipes?  Does that mean Pipes is its own namespace?

Comment: Gotcha, it's always thrown me off and I guess bad practice lead me to believe I could just tap in as many levels as I liked.   Thanks all.

Comment: @Alex: You can "tap in as many levels as you like/need", of *namespaces*. Not *classes*. (unless you are aliasing a class which is something else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing class names and namespaces and possibly the `using` directive with the `using` statement.

`System.IO` is a namespace. It's a grouping construct used to logically group classes and structs together and avoid name clashes. `System.IO.MemoryStream` is a class inside the `System.IO` namespace.

If you want to use a `MemoryStream` you can either:

```
var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(...);
```

Or, to avoid the verbosity of always specifying the namespace (a full qualified name), you can use the `using` directive:

```
using System.IO;
```

and then you can just use the class name:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(...);
```

You can think of the `using` directive as telling the compiler what search paths to use when looking for a class. If you ask for `MemoryStream` it's going to first look in the current namespace for a class named `MemoryStream`, if it doesn't find one, it's then going to look in all the namespaces that have been imported with the `using` directive (in VB.NET, I believe the equivalent directive is actually called `Imports` which, arguably, makes more sense, but there you go). If it still doesn't find a `MemoryStream` class you'll get a compile time error.

**Note:** you'll also get a compile time error if it finds more than one `MemoryStream` because it won't stop on the first one - your classes need to be unambiguous. And this is a reason not to just stuff a lot of unneeded `using` directives at the top of every `.cs` file. `MemoryStream` isn't particularly a problem here (I think it's the only `MemoryStream` in the BCL), but another class in `System.IO` is `Path`. There are several classes called `Path` in the BCL (There is another one under [System.Windows.Shapes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and without namespaces they'd be a nightmare to use.

Now, your confusion might come from the `using` statement which is often used with classes what implement `IDisposable` to ensure they get disposed. `MemoryStream` implement `IDisposable` so you'll often see things like:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(...))
{
   // some code here
}
```

Or, if they haven't used the `using` *directive* to declare the namespace:

```
using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(...))
{
    // some code here.
}
```

Which looks a lot like what you were trying to do with your `using` directive.

When looking at a class in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) there are two important things you need to look for:

> **Namespace**:  System.IO
>
> **Assemblies**:   mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)
>     System.IO (in System.IO.dll)

**Namespace** tells you what you need to include either in a `using` directive or as part of a fully qualified class name in order to use the class. The **Assemblies** part tells you which assemblies you need to add a references to your projects in order to be able to use those classes. In this case `MemoryStream` is part of the core libraries, so you aren't likely to *not* have a reference to the required assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the namespace only

```
using System.IO;
using System.Media;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using System is the right thing to do as MemoryStream is class in itself.
Right Click Project -->Add reference --> Assemblies -->System

Using System.IO

Then in code you can make object of MemoryStream.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd add one more point, regarding the format of your `using` directive. You *can* use a `using` directive very nearly like that, in order to create an alias for a namespace or class.

For instance, creating an alias for a class like this:

```
using SP = System.Media.SoundPlayer;
```

Allows you to do this:

```
var sp = new SP();
```